# Optimization methods for iOS pdf render slowness

Tags: ios, pdf, rendering

I have a pdf reader app which render the pdf file. It works fine for normal pdf files. But for some of big magazine files, it's really slow to render a page. Then I tried to upload my pdf file to GoodReader, it's slightly better than my app, but it's also very slow. That means this kind of pdf really need to be optimized before it's used for iOS device.

I've tried the Adobe Acrobat 10 to reduce the file size, but the the result is not very obvious. And I have another similar magazine pdf is rendered pretty fast in my reader. But I can't tell the difference. I think there must be some key factors will affect the pdf rendering. But unfortunately I have no idea at all.

Can anybody advise how to optimize pdf file? Are there any good software for that? Thanks

Comment: Are you "magazine files" raster images wrapped in a PDF container?

Comment: No. There are mixed text and images. The rendering is very slow even if I set the image quality to low in Indesign. But the other magazines which we use the same way to generate has no problem to be rendered. So I really don't know the key reason which cause the problem.

Comment: If you have control over the generation of your files, I would suggest to avoid complex compression algorithms such as JBIG2 and to reduce the resolution (not the compression quality) of your raster images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try your suggestion. How about the text? Are there any ways to optimize the text part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the generation of your files, I would suggest to avoid complex compression algorithms such as JBIG2 and to reduce the resolution (not the compression quality) of your raster images. JBIG2 is only used in black and white images, so maybe this is why you are getting a slow performance with some files and not with others.

Text should not be a problem in general, they are usually straight forward for rendering, but maybe you can try avoiding full embedded fonts if possible to keep the file size small.

If you will be using these files in a web scenario, I would also recommend using [Linearized PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8977648/501196).